# How access outside variables from within class?

Tags: php, oop, variables

I have two class called them class A and B. I created the 'A' class. And in this i create a 'B' class. How can i access the 'A' class variable from 'B' class?

```
class A
{
    var letter;
    var writers;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this-letter = 'SOMETHING';
        $this->writers = new B;         
    }

}

class B extends Writers
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        echo $letter; //This is where i want to acces outside variable (CLASS 'A')
    }

}
```

I hope i was clear. I'm just rookie on OOP-ing. Please help me.

Comment: Actually, I don't think this is possible. Are you forced to use this structure?

Comment: how does `B` get a reference to `A`? `A` has a `B`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't, because `$letter` in A is was not declared *public* and B doesn't extend A.

If you don't want to expose A's data (one of the important OOP principles), you should use encapsulation. Create a getter in the A class

```
public function getLetter()
{
    return $this->letter;
}
```

And then in B's construct method, create an instance of A and use said getter

```
$a = new A();
$letter = $a->getLetter();
```

Comment: Actually, "If you declare a property using var instead of one of public, protected, or private, then PHP 5 will treat the property as if it had been declared as public." (http://de1.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.properties.php). This doesn't change the essence of your answer, though.

Comment: @TheWolf Nice catch. I though `var` falled back to `protected`.

Comment: This will good if i don't do nothing else in construct, but i do lot of things. So i can't do simply get the variables.

Answer (score 1):

In case you really need to use this structure, I guess you could do something like this:

```
class A
{
    var letter;
    var writers;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this-letter = 'SOMETHING';
        $this->writers = new B($this);         
    }

}

class B extends Writers
{
    var $a;

    function __construct(A $a)
    {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->a = $a;
        echo $this->a->letter; 
    }

}
```

This way, `B` would hold a reference to the `A` object it was created by. However, I rather recommend you to change your class topology, if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Your B class needs to somehow have a reference to an A object. You could simply add to B :

```
class B extends Writers
{
    private $a;

    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        echo $letter; //This is where i want to acces outside variable (CLASS 'A')
    }

   public function A($a)
   {
        $this->a = $a;
   }
}
```

Next, simply have your A object give a reference to itself to its B object.

```
class A
{
    var letter;
    var writers;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this-letter = 'SOMETHING';
        $this->writers = new B;    
        $this->writers->A($this);
    }

}
```

The alternative would be static method.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell exactly what you want, but as I interpreted it:

```
class A extends Writers
{
    var letter;
    var writers;

    function __construct()
    {
        $this-letter = 'SOMETHING';
        $this->writers = new B;         
    }

}

class B extends A
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
        echo $this->letter; //This is where i want to acces outside variable (CLASS 'A')
    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use static variable. like this:

```
class A
{
    static $letter;
    function __construct()
    {
        self::$letter = 'SOMETHING';
    }

}
$objA = new A();

class B
{
    function __construct()
    {
        $letter = A::$letter;
        echo $letter; //print SOMETHING
    }

}
```

Comment: Using `static` to blow apart encapsulation and scope really isn't the way to go about this.